# Distinct determinants of circulants

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, enumerative-combinatorics

If $M$ is a circulant integer matrix of size $n\times n$ whose entries are randomly chosen from $\{0,1\}$ value, how many different determinants does $M$ possibly take value in?

For $n=1,2,3,4$, I have atmost $1$ or $2$ different absolute values (signed value is atmost $3$). For $n=5$, number seems $5$ different absolute values (signed value is atmost $9$). I am suspecting $O(n)$ different value.

If $M$ is symmetric and circulant, then what is the count?

Comment: Even when n is a prime, I'd expect some trouble in answering, with algebraic number theory issues. There can be units other than cyclotomic units, in other words. You are looking at norms of sums of distinct roots of unity, and looking for the unobvious equalities.

Comment: Have you tried working it out for, say, $n=1,2,3,4$ and then looking up the numbers in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences? https://oeis.org/A215723 is somewhat related.

Comment: @GerryMyerson They seem very small. I am suspecting $O(n)$ value.

Comment: So then you have worked it out for some values of $n$. May I suggest editing what you know into the body of the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Added count.

Comment: Good. But I don't think you mean *sign* at most 9.

Comment: What is a non-cyclotomic units?

Comment: @ Turbo , according to numerical experiments (until $n=17$) the number of distinct absolute values seems to be at least $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @loupblanc Please post your experiments. Maybe others will gain intuition.

Comment: @ Turbo , let $a(n)$ be the number associated to  $n$. $a(11)=23,a(12)=59,a(13)=56,a(14)=111,a(15)=223,a(16)=258,a(17)=361,a(18)=880,a(19)=1161,a(20)=2327$. Since I use a random research, the true value of $a(n)$ is $\alpha$ (the value which is given above) or $\alpha +1$ or $\alpha +2$.

Comment: $a(1)=1,a(2)=2,a(3)=3,a(4)=3,a(5)=5,a(6)=6,a(7)=9,a(8)=11,a(9)=15,a(10)=19.$                                                                                                                                                                            The values are exact until at least $n=12$. Thus this sequence is not in  oeis.org/A215723

Answer (score 2):

The exact number of distinct absolute values of determinants  for $n = 1, \dots, 22$ is

$2,2,3,3,5,6,9,11,15,19,23,59,55,111,223,258,361,880,1161,2285, 5075, 6041$

This is similar to loup blanc's list except for $a(13)$, $a(20)$ and $a(1)$.  I am not sure why we get different answers for $a(13)$

For matrices whose elements are chosen from $\{-1,1\}$ instead of $\{0,1\}$ the exact numbers for $n = 1, \dots, 24$ are:

$1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 8, 5, 12, 24, 28, 25, 112, 87, 181,215, 581, 778, 2539, 1539, 8995, 20762$

Neither of these sequences are in OEIS.